# Returning null when using INET6_ATON in LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, ipv6, inet-aton

I am using MySQL 5.6, experimenting with the new features, like `INET6_ATON` and `IS_IPV6`.
When the script reads `IPV4`, it inserts the data into the table perfectly. But when it comes to `IPv6`, one of the rows `(ipTo)` fails, even though the `INET6_ATON` works alone.

**My Table: 4 fileds**

```
`geoIPID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`IPFrom` VARBINARY(16) NOT NULL ,
`IPTo` VARBINARY(16) NOT NULL ,
`countries_countryID` INT NOT NULL
```

**A script, which loads the text files into table:**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/Invictus/Documents/htdocs/overkill/etcs/IPV6.csv' 
INTO TABLE `overkill`.`geoIP` 
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' 
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(@IPFrom, @IPTo, @dummy, @dummy, @countryAbbreviation, @dummy) 
SET IPFrom = IF(IS_IPV4(@IPFrom), 
                 INET_ATON(@IPFrom), 
                 INET6_ATON(@IPFrom)), 
    IPTo = IF(IS_IPV4(@IPTo), 
              INET_ATON(@IPTo), 
              INET6_ATON(@IPTo)), 
    countries_countryID = 
    (
      SELECT IF (COUNT(*) != 0, `countries`.`countryID`, 999) 
        FROM `countries` 
       WHERE `countries`.`countryAbbreviation` = @countryAbbreviation 
       LIMIT 1
    );
```

**The IPV4.csv file, like this:**

```
"1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","16777216","16777471","AU","Australia"
"1.0.1.0","1.0.3.255","16777472","16778239","CN","China"
"1.0.4.0","1.0.7.255","16778240","16779263","AU","Australia"
```

**The IPV6.csv file, like this:**

```
"2001:200::", "2001:200:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff", "42540528726795050063891204319802818560", "42540528806023212578155541913346768895", "JP", "Japan"
"2001:208::", "2001:208:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff", "42540529360620350178005905068154421248", "42540529439848512692270242661698371583", "SG", "Singapore"
"2001:218::", "2001:218:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff", "42540530628270950406235306564857626624", "42540530707499112920499644158401576959", "JP", "Japan"
```

**My problem:**

In case I load the `IPv6`, the second row `(ipTo)` is `NULL`. Why? All the values in the files are valid, still, MySQL does not convert them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem not in `INET6_ATON` but in your `IPV6.csv` file. Unlike `IPV4.csv` you have extra spaces after commas and that makes `LOAD DATA` read your second field like this

```
 "2001:200:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff" 
^^                                      ^
```

and that is why `INET6_ATON` returns `NULL`.

To fix this:

1. either remove extra spaces in your csv file
2. or change delimiter to `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', '`

Besides you can simplify your query and just use `INET6_ATON` instead of conditionally switching between `INET_ATON` and `INET6_ATON`. The latter works just fine with both IPV4 and IPV6.

That being said your query might look like this (**assuming that you don't have extra spaces in csv file**)

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/Invictus/Documents/htdocs/overkill/etcs/IPV6.csv' 
INTO TABLE `overkill`.`geoIP` 
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' 
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(@ipfrom, @ipto, @dummy, @dummy, @abbr, @dummy) 
SET IPFrom = INET6_ATON(@ipfrom), 
    IPTo   = INET6_ATON(@ipto), 
    countries_countryID = 
    (
      SELECT IF(COUNT(*) != 0, `countries`.`countryID`, 999) 
        FROM `countries` 
       WHERE `countries`.`countryAbbreviation` = @abbr 
       LIMIT 1
    );
```

To test things out I've removed extra spaces, combined both of your files, and loaded them into `ipv6` table. Here is the result

```
mysql> select geoIPID, HEX(ipfrom), HEX(ipto) from ipv6;
+---------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| geoIPID | HEX(ipfrom)                      | HEX(ipto)                        |
+---------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|       1 | 20010200000000000000000000000000 | 20010200FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF |
|       2 | 20010208000000000000000000000000 | 20010208FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF |
|       3 | 20010218000000000000000000000000 | 20010218FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF |
|       4 | 01000000                         | 010000FF                         |
|       5 | 01000100                         | 010003FF                         |
|       6 | 01000400                         | 010007FF                         |
+---------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select geoIPID, INET6_NTOA(ipfrom), INET6_NTOA(ipto) from ipv6;
+---------+--------------------+----------------------------------------+
| geoIPID | INET6_NTOA(ipfrom) | INET6_NTOA(ipto)                       |
+---------+--------------------+----------------------------------------+
|       1 | 2001:200::         | 2001:200:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff |
|       2 | 2001:208::         | 2001:208:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff |
|       3 | 2001:218::         | 2001:218:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff |
|       4 | 1.0.0.0            | 1.0.0.255                              |
|       5 | 1.0.1.0            | 1.0.3.255                              |
|       6 | 1.0.4.0            | 1.0.7.255                              |
+---------+--------------------+----------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```